# Using ARM ISA without their processor IP

Tags: arm

Can a semiconductor company use ARM ISA and design their own microarchitecture for it?
In that case should they still pay licensing fee to ARM.

If yes, what is stopping a company to define their own ISA and design their processor with respect to their own ISA?

Comment: This is a licensing question. Questions regarding licenses are off topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

> use ARM ISA and design their own microarchitecture for it

Yes, Qualcomm's Kryo microarch is one such product.

> should they still pay licensing fee to ARM

Yes, there are several licensing options available, but ultimately ARM will make money on chips that conform to ARM ISA

> what is stopping a company to define their own ISA and design their processor with respect to their own ISA

Convincing compiler, OS, and hardware vendor to support their shiny new ISA. RISC-V is one such attempt, with Google and Qualcomm backing.

Comment: So the reason ARM has an ISA business is because of the software environment built around it...like the compilers and OS, right?

Comment: Yep, and those ecosystems in turn exist because they filled a niche previously unserved. MIPS used to be king in consoles and supercomputers, with Android support too, but then nobody bought MIPS phones because apps using NDK are rarely compatible, and in turn, devs don't bother to include it in their build target because barely anyone uses it. Breaking into an entrenched market is just as hard as maintaining a hold (today's consoles and supercomputers are either x64 or ARM),